# Rails and URL params in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have spent hours on a very simple problem and I just don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I am trying to retrieve a value from the browser URL (.../?ref=xokKfdhVpEtG3J83MF2oXmd2) and then I want to use this value to search my Foo model by token, like this:

```
Foo.find_by(token: params[:ref])
```

My full code looks like this:

```
def extract_foo_id
 if params[:ref].present?
  @foo = Foo.find_by(token: params[:ref]).id || nil
  end
end
```

Here is how I'm trying to implement this:

```
def create
    @bar = Bar.new(bar_params)
    @bar.recruited_by = extract_foo_id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @bar.save
        format.js { render :replace_form }
      else
        format.js
      end
    end
end
```

I have made 120% sure that the token used in the example above exists by running a psql query as well as testing via ActiveRecord in the console. When I submit this action however, the result for 'recruited_by' is always null. 
I have also tried substituting the call to 'extract_foo_id' in my 'create' action, by 'Newsletter.find_by(token: params[:ref]).id'. This presents an error stating that I'm calling the 'id' method on a NULL object. I can see that the param exists when I submit my form and have even tried passing the value as a hidden field, bit for some reason it just does not seem to be able to find the record that definitely exists...

Can anybody help me find what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing all right. Small improvement on `extract_foo_id`:

```
def extract_foo_id
  raise 'no ref in params' unless params[:ref].present?
  Foo.find_by(token: params[:ref]).id
end
```

This way you will be sure that params are there.

Comment: Thanks @andrey. Do you perhaps know whether my 'find_by' is failing (Not finding a record) as a result of URL encoding or something?

Comment: @Herm Always make sure, that the datatype is matching - in this case it should be good, since token attribute (most likely) is a string, and in params everything is string. Another option is to do `Foo.where(token: params[:ref]).first.id`. So you say you are sure that `params[:ref]` returns the right token, right?

Comment: yes I am sure. I have copied the token from the browser url and pasted it into my rails console and it returns the ID without any hassles. You are correct in saying that the token is a string. Funny thing is... If I hardcode the params[:ref] section in my code, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: just to make sure - you've tried my solution, right?

Comment: I see now that you have updated your answer @andrey. I tried this new one and the error is raised. Not sure why though? My URL looks like this: 'http://localhost:3000/?ref= xokKfdhVpEtG3J83MF2oXmd2'

Comment: it is now absolutely clear, that `params[:ref]` is blank or `nil` :) From now on try to put `binding.pry` as the first line of `extract_foo_id` method and check the value, of params. see `params`, aslo `params[:ref]` - you should  getdown to it. When you're done in console - type `exit` and it will return to execution

Comment: Sorry for being a bit slow @andrey but you've lost me. I understand that 'ref' is nil, but how is that possible if I explicitly pass the value in the URL? Thanks for your help. Will definitely accept and upvote your answer when I sort this out :-)

Comment: actually there are lots of possible reasons for that, so I can't tell for sure. But if you enter the console (binding.pry) and params[:ref] is nil - you do not pass it right - can't really help you more from this point - to many things to assume. You have to just debug. My suggestion is to go step by step **starting from passing/setting the `params[:ref]`** - put `binding.pry` at **every possible** break point and track where the `params` is lost (or never set)

Comment: @Herm keep me updated, interesting, where is the spot :) I am sure it is a small think, it always like so

Answer (score 0):

you must return the value:

```
def extract_foo_id
 if params[:ref].present?
   return Foo.find_by(token: params[:ref]).try(:id)
 end
end
```

Comment: thanks but this does not seem to be the solution. The 'extract_foo_id' seems to be returning null as in it can't find the value by that ref param. Thus your solution does not give my an object error but it still does not find a Foo value related to the ref param. Might this be as a result of url encoding? I'm not sure.

Comment: can you add `puts params` to `extract_foo_id` and paste the resutls

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming strong parameters is implemented. Ensure that :recruited_by listed in your permitted params.

Comment: Hi @Tom. I am using strong parameter. I have not permitted it before but I have tried it now. This does not solve the problem. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: I noticed that your model is Bar but the params you're passing are newsletter_params. Something doesn't add up. Can you post the entirety of the controller code?

Comment: Hi @Tom. Nice spot. I have cleaned up the variable names for this question in order to make it simpler. Clearly missed that one. I have update it.